# Is $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R}$ a Dedekind cut?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathscr{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Is $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R}$ a Dedekind cut? $(*)$

**Definition.** Let $\mathscr{D} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. $\mathscr{D}$ is a Dedekind cut if the following properties hold:

- $\mathscr{D} \neq \mathbb{Q}$, $\mathscr{D} \neq \emptyset$.
- Let $d \in \mathscr{D}$. If $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q \geq d$, then $q \in \mathscr{D}$.
- Let $d \in \mathscr{D}$. Then $\exists \, a \in \mathscr{D}$ such that $a < d$.

For $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R}$ to be a Dedekind cut, it has to be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, from the definition above. But $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R} \nsubseteq \mathbb{Q}$ always (i.e. when $\mathscr{R} = \mathbb{R}$). Hence $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R}$ is not a Dedekind cut. ***I want to ask, is this statement correct, and is it enough to show that $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R}$ is not a Dedekind cut?***.

Comment: What does $-$ mean here, set difference or $\{q-r \mid q\in Q, r\in R\}$?

Comment: @AlvinL Corrected the statement in the post. $-$ means the set difference.

Comment: What is $\mathscr{R}$? - "$\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R} \subseteq \mathbb{I}$, where I is the set of irrational numbers": no, a subset of Q contains no irrational number.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}-\mathcal{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, and it is precisely never a subset of $\mathbb{I}$. That said, the answer will depend on which set $\mathcal{R}$ is chosen. If $\mathcal{R}=\emptyset$ the answer is yes (at least if your definitions are correct) and if $\mathcal{R}=\mathbb{Q}$ the answer is no.

Comment: I corrected the statement in the post.

Comment: @AlvinL When $\mathscr{R} = \mathbb{R}$, doesn't that mean that $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R} \nsubseteq \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: For a general expression such as $\mathbb{Q} - \mathscr{R}$ to be a Dedekind cut, there must be conditions which involve ordering (i.e. $<$). Otherwise it cannot meet the second bullet point of your Dedekind cut definition.

Comment: @HelloWorld The empty set is a subset of any set.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Aren't $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ ordered already?

Comment: @HelloWorld What I mean is: if you take $\mathbb Q$, then subtract any subset from it, without any condition on the subset that involves ordering, you will not get a Dedekind cut except by chance.

Comment: The answer on the general question marked as (*) is simply: no. You already provided a counterexample yourself with $\mathscr R=\mathbb R$. Then $\mathbb Q-\mathscr R$ is empty hence is not a Dedekind cut. So yes: your statement is correct and sufficient for stating the denial. Of course there are examples for $\mathscr R$ such that $\mathbb Q-\mathscr R$ is a Dedekind cut but that is not the issue here.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Alright, I understand what you're trying to say, but isn't it safe to assume that ordering holds?

Comment: @drhab Alright, nice.

Comment: Yes of course it is safe. But still, to get a Dedekind cut, you have to cut from $\mathbb Q$ a "lower part". I.e. a Dedekind cut is just the set of rationals that are $>$ to a given real number. Of course we cannot define them like that because we want to use Dedekind cuts to define real numbers, so it would be a circular definition. But still, the fact that we are cutting a "lower half" of $\mathbb Q$ should appear in $\mathscr{R}$, i.e. for $\mathbb Q - \mathscr{R}$ to be a Dedekind cut, $\mathscr{R}$ must contain a lower half of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I think I'm starting to understand what you mean.